# How to apply different font weight to Strings?

Tags: flutter, dart

From a webservice i'm getting a json where under the field "biografia" i'm getting a whole interview where Q&A are separated only by **\n** .

```
{
"biografia": "Stato civile: nubile\nPallavolo significa: tutta la mia vita\nUn difetto: mi piace molto dormire, potrei farlo tutto il giorno\nUn pregio: determinata\nLa gara più bella: Leningradka-Dinamo Mosca del 9 febbraio 2020\nLa gara da dimenticare: Nessuna; ogni partita è un’esperienza e le sconfitte ti lasciano errori su cui lavorare\nDedicherei una vittoria importante: a mia mamma, perché ha fatto e sta facendo tantissimo per me\nLibro preferito: mi piacciono romanzi e gialli\nPiatto preferito: Ratatouille\nHo scelto la pallavolo perché: mia mamma me lo fece provare quando avevo cinque anni ed è diventato la mia vita\nAdoro: il mio cane\nDetesto: lavare i piatti\nCanzone e cantante preferiti: amo la musica, ascolto diversi generi\nAuto ideale: Mercedes Benz\nSegno zodiacale: Scorpione\nIdolo sportivo: non ne ho; credo che se prendi esempio da qualcuno perdi la tua unicità e il tuo modo di giocare\nAllenatore più significativo: Vladimir Nikolaevich Merzlyakov\nCittà ideale: Mosca\nSogno nel cassetto: Top secret"},
```

What i need to achieve is a kind of interview where **the questions** are the strings before the colon and they **should be bold**, and the answers the other part.
*As I said, each block is divided by* **\n**

I don't know if it is possible to split them, modifying them by different font weight for questions and answers and put them all together in a single Text Widget.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You won't put it in a single `Text` widget, but you will put it in a `RichText` widget.

Split the output as you wish. There are a multitude of different split-questions here on StackOverflow.

Then you put it in a `RichText` widget with different `TextSpan` widgets as children.

From the official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html). Code example:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Will produce a result as:

[image]